# How to specify two devices for admob testing?

Tags: android, testing, admob

I try to put in `ads:testdevices` something like this:

```
ads:testdevices"TEST_EMULATOR, ID1, ID2"
```

but I'm afraid it is not working.

In `logcat`, there's a message

> to get test ads in this device call adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");

but I prefer to add that data to the ads layout.

And it doesn't work with two devices.

Comment: Check this: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices

Comment: The above comment is the correct solution. Want to put that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For closing as solved**

Check this: developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices